# Create docker Img from .NET Core (Console APP) that creates output file is not creating files with docker run

Tags: .net-core, dockerfile, console-application

I created a console app that saves a file correctly when executing the application. I successfully created a Docker image from the main DLL. After running the image, the code executes properly, and I can see the console WriteLine outputs. However, the file is never created. Should I use *.exe instead of *.dll to create the Docker image?
Below dockerfile

```
# Use the official .NET SDK image as a build environment
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project file and restore dependencies
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy the remaining source code and build the application
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Define the runtime environment
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

# Create a directory for logs and grant permissions
RUN mkdir /log && chmod 777 /log

# Set the entry point for the container
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myassembly.dll"]
```

Comment: It is important to know that at which location you are writing the file. For that what are doing while you run docker image that command is required and some part of code that actually write file. It may writing the file but it is inside docker container.